# Nginx & multiple php-fpm version

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I try to serve several sites based on different versions of PHP with Nginx  & Ubuntu 20.04).
So I installed php-fpm versions 5.6 and 7.4 and configured Nginx like this:

```
server {
  root /var/www;
  server_name xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx; # managed by Certbot
  index index.php;
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  # PHP 5 locations
  location /site5 {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
  }

  # PHP 7 locations
  location /site7 {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  if ($host = xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot
  listen 80 ;
  listen [::]:80 ;
  server_name xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Pages running phpinfo() under site5 & site7 works well and tell me the right versions for each site.

But I have problems with static content.

First of all, the referenced images were returning a 403. The error log from Nginx said :

`"Access to the script '/var/www/site7/whatever.jpg' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)"`

After changing the value of `security.limit_extensions` to `false` in `/etc/php/fpm/7.4/pool.d/www.conf`, the images are displayed correctly.

But now if I access an image directly via its URL, either it is returned as text (with the Content-Type text/html), or I get a 404 (even though the file is there).

The www-data user is the owner of the files and the permissions are 755.

I have never used PHP with fpm so I am completely lost...
So I have two questions:

- Is it problematic to set `security.limit_extensions` to `false` ?
- What can I do to ensure that the files, whatever they are, are accessible ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration passes requests to all resources to the PHP, which is not what you want.

If you have only URLs with `.php` extension included, then following approach works:

```
location ~ ^/site5.*\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ ^/site7.*\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

However, if your application implements front-controller pattern, then you need extra setup:

```
location /site5 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ site5/index.php;
}

location /site7 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ site7/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Which one did you use?

Comment: Both actually.
I moved all php5 sites under a php5 dir and set
"location ~ ^/php5.*\.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
}"
And for every location
"location /site5 {
  try_files $uri $uri/ site5/index.php;
}"
Same thing for php7 sites